# ActiveMQ CPP brokers URI problem

Tags: c++, jms, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I'm using ActiveMQ CPP 5.2.3.

I'm trying to add `transport.commandTracingEnabled=true` to tcp transport layer:

```
failover://(tcp://10.10.10.1:61616transport.commandTracingEnabled=true,tcp://10.10.10.2:61616?transport.commandTracingEnabled=true)?randomize=true
```

ActiveMQ doesn't accept it.

Hovewer with one TCP transport it works fine:

```
failover://(tcp://10.10.10.1:61616transport.commandTracingEnabled=true)?randomize=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean version 3.2.3.

Can you expand on what "ActiveMQ doesn't accept it" means?

Looks like you're missing a '?' character after the first ip/port

```
failover://(tcp://10.10.10.1:61616transport.commandTracingEnabled=true,tcp://10.10.10.2:61616?transport.commandTracingEnabled=true)?randomize=true
```

There are some URI fixes coming in v3.2.5 which might help also.